# keeps on getting expected 'const char *'

Tags: c

im a first year college student so i dont know much about c.
we have an assignment about making airplane seating using array, my code keeps on saying expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char' And passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without cast specifically on lines 92:2 94:2 96:2.... till 107:2, then 155:2 to 178:2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char first_class();
void business_class();

int main()

{

int row,class = 0;

char X;


char seating[13][6] ={ 
{X, X, '*', '*', '*', '*'},{'*','*',X,X,'*','*'},{X,X,X,'*','*',X},{'*','*','*',X,X,'*'},{X,X,X,X,X,X},{'*','*',X,X,'*','*'},{'*',X,'*','*',X,X},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{X,'*','*','*',X,'*'},{X,X,X,'*','*','*'},{X,X,X,X,X,X},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*',X,X,X,'*','*'} };

int i,j;
int a;

char c;
char seat;





printf("*********************************************************\n");

printf("****   Thank you for choosing Ricardio's Airline.    ****\n");

printf("**  Best seats available for your flight, guaranteed,  **\n");

printf("****            Refund is not available              ****\n");

printf("*********************************************************\n");



printf("We have the best seats in da haus yo!\n");

printf("Please select a Class\n");

printf("1 = First Class, 2 = Business Class, 3 = Economy Class\n:");

scanf("%d", &class);


for(c='A'; c<='G'; ++c)

    printf("\t %c", c);
printf("\n");
for(i = 0;i < 14; i++)

{

    printf("Row %d", i);

    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
    printf("\t seating[i][j]");

    if (j % 6 == 0)

    printf("\n");

}
}

if (class == 1)

first_class();        



else if (class == 2)

business_class();



else if (class == 3)

printf ("economy_class()");



else

printf("Invalid Class");     
if(strcmp(seat, "1C") == 0)
    seating[0][2] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "1D") == 0)
    seating[0][3] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "1E") == 0)
    seating[0][4] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "1F") == 0)
    seating[0][5] = X;

if(strcmp(seat, "2A") == 0)
    seating[1][0] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "2B") == 0)
    seating[1][1] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "2E") == 0)
    seating[1][4] = X;
if(strcmp(seat, "2F") == 0)
    seating[1][5] = X;

for(c='A'; c<='G'; ++c)

    printf("\t %c", c);
printf("\n");
for(i = 0;i < 14; i++)

{

    printf("Row %d", i);

    for(j = a; j < 7; j++){

    printf("\t seating[i][j]");

    if (j % 6 == 0)

    printf("\n");
}
}

return 0;
}       


char first_class()
{

int row = 0;
char column;
char seat;        

printf ("*******************************************************\n");

printf ("*                      First Class                    *\n");

printf ("*******************************************************\n");



printf ("Rows 1 and 2 are reserved for First Class seating.\n");

printf ("Which seat would you like?\n");

scanf("%s", seat);

if(strcmp(seat, "1A") == 0)
    printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
if(strcmp(seat, "1B") == 0)
    printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
if(strcmp(seat, "1C") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "1D") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "1E") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "1F") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);

if(strcmp(seat, "2A") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "2B") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "2C") == 0)
    printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
if(strcmp(seat, "2D") == 0)
    printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
if(strcmp(seat, "2E") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
if(strcmp(seat, "2F") == 0)
    printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);

else

printf("Invalid Row or That Row Is For The Other Classes");
return seat;
}
void business_class()

{
int column;
int row = 0;

printf ("*******************************************************\n");

printf ("*                   Business Class                    *\n");

printf ("*******************************************************\n");



printf ("Rows 3,4,5,7 and 8 are reserved for First Class seating.\n");

printf ("Which row would you like?\n");

scanf("%d", row);

if(row = 3)

printf("Please select your coloumn\n");

scanf("%s",column);

    if(column = 'A')
    printf("Hi");

if(row = 4)

printf("Please select your coloumn\n");

else

printf("Invalid Row or That Row Is For The Other Classes");
}
```

Comment: More precisely, which line is generating this warning?

Comment: Please care to format the code before posting it.

Comment: Change `if(strcmp(seat, "1A") == 0)` etc to `if (memcmp((char*)seat, "1A",strlen("1A")) == 0)`

Comment: the error changes to "cast to pointer from integer of different sizes [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh please @DarenCoffey It's not PHP don't use `strlen()` like that!

Comment: Its Mingw for windows7

Comment: @ihorab What is your logic for not using strlen with a const string? What is  your suggestion for an alternative?  It's less error prone than manually counting the characters, you don't have to remember to subtract the null character out as you would with sizeof("string"), and on a modern compiler, all three methods generate the exact same code.

Comment: @DarenCoffey no, don't use redundant casts. That would make things worse anyway.

Comment: I think you meant `'X'` everywhere you wrote `X`. The former is the character `'X'`. The latter is the name of a variable that has not got a value.

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this code it's hard to know where to start. Really, you should be making a much smaller program , check that everything works as intended , and then add new features one at a time.

Comment: @M.M You're right. I honestly didn't look at the code that closely and didn't realize `char seat` was missing the pointer operator, and did a quick "make it compile" fix. I'm kinda spoiled by cpp so it slipped my mind that you don't have to cast pointers to void pointers. That definitely would not have worked as intended.

Comment: You don't have to cast to void pointers in C++ either

Comment: please consistently indent the code.  suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: the posted code contains lots of syntax problems.  (pages of warnings and errors) Always enable all warnings when compiling, and fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: the posted code is returning a local variable 'seat', but when that variable is changed to be an array, then the code will fail as `seat[]` is on the stack and returning it will return a pointer to it.   the seat[] array is not valid after it 'goes out of scope',  If going to return  seat, then use malloc() to allocate the bytes in the seat[] array, and return the seat pointer to that malloc'd memory.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems in your script. Firt, you must change the line 139

```
char seat;
```

for the follow:

```
char *seat;
```

Because you deal with the variable seat like an string, just char mean a character. Other observations is that you need pass the direction of the variable with scanf, thus, you must replace the follow lines:

```
scanf("%s",column);
scanf("%d",row);
```

by

```
scanf("%d",&column);
scanf("%d",&row);
```

Note that en the second you must change the type of the variable to '%d' (integer). On the other hand, you have a function first_class that return a char, but, you want return the variable seat that ir a string, thus, you must replace the function definition by

```
char* first_class()
```

Also, to compare variables you must use the operator ==, see the function business_class. your final code must be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *first_class();
void business_class();

int main()
{

  int row,class = 0;
  char X;
  char seating[13][6] ={ 
  {X, X, '*', '*', '*', '*'},{'*','*',X,X,'*','*'},{X,X,X,'*','*',X},{'*','*','*',X,X,'*'},{X,X,X,X,X,X},{'*','*',X,X,'*','*'},{'*',X,'*','*',X,X},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{X,'*','*','*',X,'*'},{X,X,X,'*','*','*'},{X,X,X,X,X,X},{'*','*','*','*','*','*'},{'*',X,X,X,'*','*'} };

  int i,j;
  int a;

  char c;
  char *seat;
  seat = (char *) malloc(15); 




  printf("*********************************************************\n");

  printf("****   Thank you for choosing Ricardio's Airline.    ****\n");

  printf("**  Best seats available for your flight, guaranteed,  **\n");

  printf("****            Refund is not available              ****\n");

  printf("*********************************************************\n");



  printf("We have the best seats in da haus yo!\n");

  printf("Please select a Class\n");

  printf("1 = First Class, 2 = Business Class, 3 = Economy Class\n:");

  scanf("%d", &class);


  for(c='A'; c<='G'; ++c)
      printf("\t %c", c);
  printf("\n");

  for(i = 0;i < 14; i++)
  {
      printf("Row %d", i);
      for(j = 0; j < 7; j++)
      {
        printf("\t seating[i][j]");
        if (j % 6 == 0)
           printf("\n");
      }
  }

  if (class == 1)
    first_class();        
  else if (class == 2)
    business_class();
  else if (class == 3)
    printf ("economy_class()");
  else
    printf("Invalid Class");     


  if(strcmp(seat, "1C") == 0)
      seating[0][2] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "1D") == 0)
      seating[0][3] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "1E") == 0)
      seating[0][4] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "1F") == 0)
      seating[0][5] = X;

  if(strcmp(seat, "2A") == 0)
      seating[1][0] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "2B") == 0)
      seating[1][1] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "2E") == 0)
      seating[1][4] = X;
  if(strcmp(seat, "2F") == 0)
      seating[1][5] = X;

  for(c='A'; c<='G'; ++c)
      printf("\t %c", c);
  printf("\n");

  for(i = 0;i < 14; i++)
  {
      printf("Row %d", i);
      for(j = a; j < 7; j++){
        printf("\t seating[i][j]");
        if (j % 6 == 0)
           printf("\n");
      }
  }

  return 0;
}       


char* first_class()
{

  int row = 0;
  char column;
  char *seat;  

  printf ("*******************************************************\n");

  printf ("*                      First Class                    *\n");

  printf ("*******************************************************\n");



  printf ("Rows 1 and 2 are reserved for First Class seating.\n");

  printf ("Which seat would you like?\n");

  scanf("%s", seat);


  if(strcmp(seat, "1A") == 0)
      printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
  if(strcmp(seat, "1B") == 0)
      printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
  if(strcmp(seat, "1C") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "1D") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "1E") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "1F") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);

  if(strcmp(seat, "2A") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "2B") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "2C") == 0)
      printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
  if(strcmp(seat, "2D") == 0)
      printf("The seat you have chosen is already taken");
  if(strcmp(seat, "2E") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);
  if(strcmp(seat, "2F") == 0)
      printf("You have chosen seat %d %c", row,column);

  else

  printf("Invalid Row or That Row Is For The Other Classes");
  return seat;
}




void business_class()
{
  int column;
  int row = 0;

  printf ("*******************************************************\n");
  printf ("*                   Business Class                    *\n");
  printf ("*******************************************************\n");
  printf ("Rows 3,4,5,7 and 8 are reserved for First Class seating.\n");
  printf ("Which row would you like?\n");
  scanf("%d", &row);

  if(row == 3)
      printf("Please select your coloumn\n");
  scanf("%d",&column);

  if(column == 'A')
      printf("Hi");

  if(row == 4)
      printf("Please select your coloumn\n");
  else
      printf("Invalid Row or That Row Is For The Other Classes");
}
```

Comment: this will NOT work: `char *seat;` because then there needs to be a `malloc()` call to allocate memory to the variable `seat` to point at.   Suggest using: `char seat[5];`  Otherwise the call to scanf() will result in undefined behaviour and may result in a seg fault event.

Comment: this answer does not compile.  There are several un-initialized variables that are being used.

Comment: yes, you are rigth. I added the follow line seat = (char *) malloc(15); I use the compiler gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: Suggest adding the parameters `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to the compile step so the compiler will raise the warnings about the unused/uninitialized variables

Answer (score 0):

regarding this kind of line:

```
if(strcmp(seat, "1C") == 0)
```

seat`is a single character and`"1C"` is a string that (including the trailing NUL char) is 3 bytes.

So the single char cannot be compared to a string.

Also, this kind of line:

```
scanf("%s", seat);
```

says to read a string into the single char variable `seat`.

If the user enters anything beyond a `<newline>` the buffer will be overrun!

(scanf() always appends a NUL char when reading a string)

A buffer overrun is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Suggest declaring the variable `seat` as

```
char seat[5];
```

and modifying the call to `scanf()` to limit the max number of chars input to 1 less than the the length of seat[]  I.E.

```
scanf( '%4s", seat);
```

Please correct all such problems in the code, via a edit that appends the corrected code.